# Using gMSA account for SQL server reporting services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, ssrs

I am trying to configure SSRS on my VM:s via gMSA account which does not seem to work and unable to access the reporting url ( Web Portal URL) link  to check configuration.

The requirement is to have services hosted on different VM's than its report server and report server TempDB databases. So on server A and B simply running SSRS services fails when using gMSA during the configuration steps in reporting server configuration utility. I am using same gMSA on 2 other database servers as well.

> Error" The report server cannot connect to report server database due
> to logon failure. User name and password incorrect"

Using setup as mentioned here: [Configure a Native Mode Report Server Scale-Out Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-a-native-mode-report-server-scale-out-deployment?view=sql-server-ver15)

Is gMSA supported for scale out or there is something I am missing here?

Comment: Have you tested your gMSA account?
Powershell --> Test-ADServiceAccount your_gMSA

Comment: It says True on all servers

Comment: Are the [Software requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview#BKMK_SOFT) met? Also, are the other 2 servers you configured the gMSA working fine with that credential?

Answer (score 0):

GMSA is not supported for running SSRS service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-the-report-server-service-account-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16#choosing-an-account

[image]